# usort changing Array's order

Tags: php, usort

I have a usort function with a single line: return 0. 
I tried to use it on an Array of stdClass objects, and it changes 
their order, how is that possible?

Comment: tried it with uasort as well, still changed the order

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JPvvxJaC - change the uasort to usort, it will still change the order

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The property you assume is called [*stability*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability): A *stable* sorting algorithm will not change the order of elements that are equal.

php's sorting functions are **not** stable (because non-stable sorts may be slightly faster). From the [documentation of `usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> If two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is
>   undefined.

If you want a stable sorting algorithm, you must [implement it yourself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#38827).

Comment: Thanks for this! FYI though (with PHP 7.1.9): "Type error: array_slice() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given". It seems to be fixed by using `$halfway = intval(count($array) / 2);` instead, but I'm not sure if this screws something else up (is it important to slice the array *exactly* in the middle?)

Answer (score 1):

It's because that function means "I really don't care how they are sorted, they are equal to me". With this simple sample I receive reversed array:

```
function sortaaa($a,$b) {return 0;}
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
usort($array,"sortaaa");
var_dump($array);
//prints array(5) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(1) }
```

So it looks like PHP loops the array in reverse order in function `usort`. So, note the `usort` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) states that

> If two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

Comment: what would you suggest as a solution?

Comment: That depends on what do you mean by solution. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Asaf If stability is such an issue, roll out your own sorting routine. Added a [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#38827) to one to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283877/usort-changing-arrays-order/7283968#7283968).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick solution for a *stable* `usort`, you could use `uksort` like in the following example:

```
<?php

uksort($array, function ($ak, $bk) use ($array) {
    $a = $array[$ak];
    $b = $array[$bk];

    if ($a['foo'] === $b['foo']) 
        return $ak - $bk;

    return $a['foo'] > $b['foo'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

This works as expected only if the initial indices (keys) of `$array` are in ascending order.