# Move elements of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm receiving an array from a database - I have no control over what pieces of data are sent and in what order. This is what it currently looks like:

```
Array
(
    [itemCode] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => P
                    [descShort] => Pepperoni
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [code] => G
                    [descShort] => Green Peppers
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [code] => n
                    [descShort] => No Sauce
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [code] => x
                    [descShort] => No Cheese
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 
                    [descShort] => Regular Cheese
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 
                    [descShort] => Regular Sauce
                )

        )

)
```

In actual practice, there can be any number of elements before the No Sauce option (currently at index 3, but not always that way.) What the client wants is for the Cheese and Sauce items to always be at the end of the list and ordered this way: Regular Cheese, No Cheese, Regular Sauce, No Sauce.

Again, keeping in mind that I have no control over how the array is initially created, and that there could be any number of other elements both before and between the elements in question, how can I make this happen? Something else to worry about is that at some point, there may be other options they want to include in this re-ordering (they may add an option for Extra Cheese and Extra Sauce, for example, and want them to be in specific positions as well.)

**Added var_export**

```
array (
  'itemCode' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'code' => 'P',
      'descShort' => 'Pepperoni',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'code' => 'G',
      'descShort' => 'Green Peppers',
    ),

    2 => 
    array (
      'code' => 'n',
      'descShort' => 'No Sauce',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'code' => 'x',
      'descShort' => 'No Cheese',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'code' => '',
      'descShort' => 'Regular Cheese',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'code' => '',
      'descShort' => 'Regular Sauce',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Add the code where you query that from the database. It might be trivial to just extend the SQL query doing the work, so you won't need to change the output code.

Comment: It's not SQL; it's Cache. And as I said - I have no control over how the array comes to me. That CANNOT be changed; I have to work with what I've shown above.

Comment: Hey, that was a suggestion, nothing to offend you. It was not clear to me that this is static data. Take it lightly ;)

Comment: Yes, but often if users say database and "I can not change it", it's not true and the answer then is a different SQL query. Anyway, that is not your fault nor my fault ;) Comments help to clarify this quickly.

Comment: Also your question makes me hungry.

Comment: Yeah, that's the hazard of working on a pizza restaurant's site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been already commented, the [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) function can be used for that. But this is only the start as it needs the compare function.

That is also not that hard, because we can just create one. However, it's crucial to understand how it works:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Okay, that's not a blocker but turns the actual question, how to find out which one is above which one? And how to do that extensible?

There are two type of values: Either the ones that do not need any ordering or the ones that need ordering. Let's first define an array for those that need ordering. And to make it clear for what that ordering is, name the key:

```
$order    = 'descShort';
$ordering = ['Regular Cheese', 'No Cheese', 'Regular Sauce', 'No Sauce'];
```

Now inside a compare function, you can look up if for the A/B values an entry exists within the ordering. If it does not exists, then this needs no ordering. If it exists, this needs ordering.

These two cases are extended because you also can have an existing sort order with a non-existing one. So there are four cases to cover:

1. A and B do not exists - treat them equal -- 0
2. A and B exist - sort according to their order-value  -- calculate position A - B
3. A exists but not B - A is greater than B -- 1
4. B exists but not A - A is less than B -- -1

Thanks to function support in PHP, we can pass along the order-key and the ordering values into the comparison function easily for a quick example. The function then only has to do what has been outlined for the four cases.

The example:

```
$order    = 'descShort';
$ordering = ['Regular Cheese', 'No Cheese', 'Regular Sauce', 'No Sauce'];
$compare  = function($a, $b) use ($order, $ordering) {
    $hasA = array_search($a[$order], $ordering);
    $hasB = array_search($b[$order], $ordering);

    // nothing to sort
    if ($hasA === $hasB && $hasA === FALSE) {
        return 0;
    }

    // if both are found, sort
    if ($hasA !== FALSE && $hasB !== FALSE) {
        return $hasA - $hasB;
    }

    // as one of them is in there, put it to end
    return $hasA === FALSE ? -1 : 1;
};

usort($array['itemCode'], $compare);
```

So now there is one caveat: `usort` is not stable. That means, when returning 0, items do not stay at their position. You can work around that by sorting once again the same with `usort`.

```
usort($array['itemCode'], $compare);
```

Then the final sort order is ([Demo](http://eval.in/2433)):

```
Array
(
    [itemCode] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => P
                    [descShort] => Pepperoni
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [code] => G
                    [descShort] => Green Peppers
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 
                    [descShort] => Regular Cheese
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [code] => x
                    [descShort] => No Cheese
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 
                    [descShort] => Regular Sauce
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [code] => n
                    [descShort] => No Sauce
                )
        )
)
```

---

As there was a problem with stable sort and I'm also not that well with it (the suggested function looks a bit like an overhead to me in your case here), there is just good old `foreach`.

And as there are no duplicate values for those to be sorted later on, well, this leaves some nifty room:

```
$order    = 'descShort';
$ordering = ['Regular Cheese', 'No Cheese', 'Regular Sauce', 'No Sauce'];

$result = []; // the final result
$later  = []; // to be sorted later
foreach($array as $element)
{

    $has = array_search($element[$order], $ordering);
    if ($has !== FALSE) {
        $later[$has] = $element;
        continue;
    }

    $result[] = $element;
}
```

It is just straight ahead for-eaching over the array, putting all values into `$result` already that are *not* part of the ordering.

Those that are part of the ordering are put into `$later` with their order value as index already.

Only `$later` then is sorted with `ksort`, and then the two parts are merged:

```
ksort($later);
$result = array_merge($result, $later);
```

And done. No callback function needed. Just first filtering, and the indexing with the sort value together with `ksort` does the magic. [Demo](http://eval.in/2442).

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. It will take me a bit of time to implement and test.

Comment: Well, it would have been nice... unfortunately it blew up - throws an error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\gitRepo\mysite\application\controllers\menu.php on line 498` where line 498 is line 47 of your eval.in file (`$ordering = ['Regular Cheese', 'No Cheese', 'Regular Sauce', 'No Sauce'];`). Is there a reason you're using square brackets instead of making that an array as well, with `array('item1', 'item')`?

Comment: I changed it out to standard array format, and it doesn't seem to work. I forked your code and put in my actual array (with all the other stuff I had removed for readability) and it doesn't seem to do the sort at all. [Demo](http://eval.in/2435)

Comment: Look for these errors: *"Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null"* - you don't pass the array to usort, as you've changed the format, the key is not necessary any longer: http://eval.in/2439 simple fix. However, the search is not stable.

Comment: If you need stable, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#38827 (via http://stackoverflow.com/q/7283877/367456)

Comment: Thanks, @hakre. I definitely do need stable. I admit that this is a bit further than I've gone into dealing with arrays, though - in the function shown at php.net, where exactly do I provide my list of terms to include in the sort? I don't want the entire array subjected to the sort, only items that meet certain criteria. I'm guessing that ` $cmp_function = 'strcmp'` has something to do with it, but have no idea how to go from there to my list of options to include.

Comment: That would have been the `$compare` function. However it's probably even easier, to just sort the part that needs sorting and then merge it with the part that does not need sorting. That's also what I suggested in one of my earlier comments. I edit the answer showing you how that could be done.

Comment: I really appreciate all the time you've spent on this, but even your demo still doesn't work the way it needs to. The whole point of this is to a) move all the sauce and cheese options to the end of the list, and b) to have them in the order listed in the $ordering variable. In your demo, they're not in that order. I realize that there are other sauce/cheese options in the return array that are not in the list, but even when I add those options into the $ordering list, as [here](http://eval.in/2445), they come out in the wrong order.

Comment: Note that the ONLY thing I changed in that last eval paste is to add options to the $ordering variable; the rest of your code is untouched. The results come out in this order: Extra Cheese, Extra Sauce, Easy on Sauce, Easy on Cheese, No Sauce, No Cheese, Regular Sauce, Regular Cheese. They need to be in this order: Regular Cheese, Extra Cheese, Easy on Cheese, No Cheese, Regular Sauce, Extra Sauce, Easy on Sauce,  No Sauce. It's sorting by the first word of the shortDesc, which isn't correct. I don't need an alphabetical sort, but an arbitrary sort.

Comment: Lol, the last line is wrong: `print_r($array);` should be `print_r($result);` ;) Otherwise not the result, but the original array is displayed. **Edit:** http://eval.in/2447 - also check if the ordering array is still correct. I might have replaced it with a smaler version.

Comment: Sorry, but still not correct. [Demo](http://eval.in/2446) Maybe I'm not explaining myself well enough. The array elements that match what is in the $ordering variable need to end up at the end of the full array, and in the order they're shown in the $ordering variable. That isn't happening.

Comment: @EmmyS: See http://eval.in/2452 - This is basically the right output. If some sauces / cheeses are not sorted then because their value is not found in the ordering array. `"Easy on Sauce"` is different then `"Easy On Sauce"` (see the O). So take care you really have the correct values in there, otherwise it will not find them and add them to the upper part of the result. That simple it is. And I never put alphabetical sorting in there. Just FYI.

Comment: Arggghhh! I hate it when I miss something so stupid and it makes such a huge difference. It was indeed the lowercase vs. capital O. I'd like to believe that if I hadn't been staring at this for so long I'd have caught it myself. Maybe, maybe not. In any case, thank you so much for your patience and assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which will allow a user-defined sort.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. Yes, I know about usort; what I'm having trouble with is figuring out HOW to create something that will sort these items in the way I need them to be sorted.

Comment: @EmmyS: You could also filter the array. In the first round you take over that is okay, on the second run, you take over what belongs to the end.

Comment: It's not just a matter of moving items to the end, though - they have to be in a specific order. That's what I don't know how to do.

Comment: Please add a `var_export` of the array to your question instead of a `print_r`.

Comment: Added a var_export, @hakre. Not sure what you can get out of it that's not in the print_r. (Noticed a mis-numbering in the origining print_r; that was just a typo - I removed a bunch of elements to make it easier to read.)

Comment: It's more easy to create an example with the actual values as that is valid PHP. Just keep it in mind for your next questions, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the user-defined sort that you want. The array `$last_options` lists all the toppings that should be sorted to the end, and their order in the array specifies the order they should appear in the result.

```
$last_options = array('Regular Cheese', 'No Cheese', 'Regular Sauce', 'No Sauce');

function topping_order($a, $b) {
  $a_pos = array_search($a['descShort'], $last_options);
  $b_pos = array_search($b['descShort'], $last_options);
  if ($a_pos !== false && $b_pos !== false) {
    if ($a_pos > $b_pos) {
      return 1;
    }
    if ($b_pos > $a_pos) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  if ($a_pos === false) {
    return -1;
  }
  if ($b_pos === false) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

usort($array, 'topping_order');
```

Comment: I tried yours as well, and get some crazy stuff, aside from the fact that it doesn't sort correctly at all. [Demo](http://eval.in/2437) Any ideas?

Comment: these are the errors it throws; it doesn't seem to be recognizing `$last_options` as an array.

`Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /tmp/execpad-1adb6d7b8e9d/source-1adb6d7b8e9d on line 385

Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /tmp/execpad-1adb6d7b8e9d/source-1adb6d7b8e9d on line 386`

where those two lines are the two array_search lines in `topping_order()`.

Comment: Moving the definition of `$last_options` inside the function gets rid of the warnings, but still doesn't sort correctly. [Demo](http://eval.in/2438)

Comment: Adding a `global $last_options;` statement would also have fixed it. But hakre's answer is more succinct and I think it should work just as well.